# Drop rows WHERE date is a certain condition Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a dataset where I would like to remove all rows where the date is 4/1/2022 within a column in my dataset. The Date column is datetime64ns

**Data**

```
ID Date
AA 1/1/2022
BB 1/1/2022
CC 4/1/2022
```

**Desired**

```
ID Date
AA 1/1/2022
BB 1/1/2022
```

**Doing**

```
   new = df[df['Date'].str.contains('4/1/2022')==False]
```

However, this is not a string, it is datetime. This is not removing the rows at all. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `I would like to remove all rows where the date is 4/1/2022` It appears that the code is doing the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df['Date'].ne('2022-04-01')]
```

Output:

```
   ID       Date
0  AA 2022-01-01
1  BB 2022-01-01
```

If for some reason you need to use [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) (e.g. to modify a DataFrame in place):

```
m = df['Date'].eq('2022-04-01')

df.drop(m[m].index, inplace=True)
```

##### multiple dates

```
df[~df['Date'].isin(['2022-04-01', '2022-04-03'])]
```

Comment: this works well - thank you @mozway - will review the documentation - could this be used for multiple dates

Comment: thank you - will look at documentation and learn this. Big help!

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. coerce the date to string and filter

```
df[~df['Date'].astype(str).str.contains('4/1/2022')]
```